# $("#container").tinycarousel is not a function

Tags: jquery

i'm using tinycarousel, and for some reason, when i run $("#container").tinycarousel(); it keeps telling me it's not a function. could someone please point me in the right way to debug?

any help would be much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.tinycarousel.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
    <ul class="overview">
        <li>
            some content
        </li>
        <li>
            Some content
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the .js file is in the right location? What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: The built-in Developer Tools in Chrome or Safari, or Firebug, will tell you if the js file loaded.

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle.net?  You can include jQuery natively and link to tinycarousel somewhere on the web.  That'd help us debug.

Comment: how do you check if the file is loaded?

Comment: @laurenceputra, to check if the file is loaded or not, please see answer of Paul.

Comment: the file is loaded. what the possible scenarios that lead to things like this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
 <div id="container">
        <a class="buttons prev" href="#">left</a>
        <div class="viewport">
            <ul class="overview">
                <li><img src="images/picture3.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/picture2.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="buttons next" href="#">right</a>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                
        $('#container').tinycarousel();
        
    });
</script>
```

Your code is missing the required viewport `div`. And you should initiate the tinycarousel after the DOM is ready, which you can achieve with the `$(document).ready` event listener.

Read the instructions on [baijs.nl/tinycarousel](http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel). It has several examples example you can download and try out. I'm the author, so if something isn't clear or missing please notify me.

Comment: thanks. i think you shld have a specs somewhere that says which parts exactly are needed. thanks =D